# why is my proof that f(A\B)=f(A)\f(B) wrong?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, functions

given f, a function from C to D, and given A,B subsets of C. prove/disprove: f(A\B)=f(A)\f(B).
so I said let's take y in f(A\B) and then y=f(x) for x in A\B. 
so x in A, x not in B it means that y in f(A), y not in f(B), so y is in f(A)\f(B). 
Now taking y in f(A)\f(B).  So y in f(A) but not in f(B), so taking y=f(x), x in A and not in B. so x in A\B.
Why is my proof not valid?

Answer (score 1):

Let’s look at an actual counterexample: $C=\{-1,0,1\}$, $D=\{0,1\}$, $A=\{0,1\}$, $B=\{-1\}$, and $f(x)=x^2$ for $x\in C$. Then

$$f[A\setminus B]=f[A]=\{0,1\}\,,$$

but

$$f[A]\setminus f[B]=\{0,1\}\setminus\{1\}=\{0\}\,.$$

The problem with your argument is that if $f$ is not injective there may be $x\notin B$ and $x'\in B$ such that $f(x)=f(x')$, so that $f(x)\in f[B]$ even though $x\notin $B$.

Answer (score 0):

$x \notin B$ does not tell you that $f(x) \notin f(B)$. It is possible that $f(x)=f(y)$ for some $y \in B$ in which case$f(x)$ does belong to $f(B)$.

For  a counter-example to $f(A\setminus B)=f(A)\setminus f(B)$ take $A=\emptyset, B=(0,\infty)$ and $f(x)=x^{2}$.